# Get value of Delphi text field outside of the program

Tags: delphi, winapi

Hopefully someone might point me in the right direction.

So there's a very simple and old Delphi program run on a computer, and I have no access to the source or its DB. I can only run the .exe

I would like a way to somehow read several strings from TEdit controls in this program and dump them to a simple .txt file on the same computer. It also prints the data every time something new comes up, so maybe there's a way to catch it while it's being sent to the printer. This is where my ideas end.

How would I go about doing this? Some kind of listener utility? Win32 API? The OS is Win7.

P.S. It's not for hacking :) so no need to hide anything. Can be in plain sight.

EDIT:
Ok, since everyone started focusing on the wrong things, I'll try to explain exactly what I need this for.

First of all, programming is "only" an on and off hobby of mine. And I still consider myself very much a beginner. But whereas before I would just take a huge book on, say, the C language and read it, without getting anything done, and the having life get in the way, now I've decided that maybe a better way would be to have a concrete project in mind and be driven and focused towards it. That way I'll have a specific goal and will try to learn only the things and technologies I need to achieve it. It will also help me in overcoming the confusion of what language/technology to pick out of so many.

That's where my question comes from. My actual job has nothing to do with programming or IT. Nor do we have any access or any say in the software that we use. One of the programs - the one I am talking about - is a simple register: a client comes, our employee adds an entry to the register, and the program prints out (hence I was thinking I could catch the info when sent to printer) two receipts with a number. One goes to the client, the other stays with us. We have a very primitive system in place that allows the client to look up his order status using his receipt number (basically "Done" or "Not done"). The info is stored in a small DB on our website. I *do* have access to our DB and our info. I *do not* have any access to the source of register program, nor its DB. I can modify neither. I can only run it. Hence the question.

What we do now is - an employee then literally takes the piece of paper, opens our website and adds the new entry by hand. Then, when the time comes, he changes its status. My idea is to simplify everyone's life: somehow catch the receipt number (and other info) DURING the entry creation process on that Delphi register program (while the client is still there, before our employee click "Ok" and creates the entry), dump it to a .txt file, and later on develop something to automatically upload the info in bulk to our own DB. So that no one has to input it by hand which is pointless and tedious. The problem is that, like I said, I have no access to the program's source or its DB. It's a fact and there's no point in suggesting we change the fact. We can't. I do have access to the physical computer the program runs on, and of course I have access to our website and our DB. Hopefully this makes sense.

Again, my job has nothing to do with IT, so this would be a free time hobby project to get me back into programming but with a specific goal in mind. It seems like a lofty goal but I have no other ideas honestly. That's why I said I am ready to consider any technology and any language. Delphi is tagged only because the register software is Delphi. I actually know very little/nothing about Delphi so if this can be done in some other language (C or .Net or a script of some kind...), I would appreciate the pointers.

Comment: "It's not for hacking" - This is hacking no matter what way you look at it. The term "hacker" is very vague, and isn't necessarily a bad thing. But in any case, this question is off-topic on Stack Overflow for multiple reasons. But to get you going somewhere, you say there's a DB, but you can't access it. Well, that *should* be where you extract such data. It should be **MUCH** easier to access the database than to try and read from the application.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about somehow reading it from the textfield component in real time as the data is being introduced, or catching it when it's sent to print. Can be any language and any technology. And guys, I'm on my phone right now, so I'm limiting the amount of typing, but once I get home, I'll gladly explain what this is for exactly, no secret at all. It's a hobby project to teach myself but with a practical real-life application if done right. And no, let's assume the DB is inaccessible.

Comment: Regardless of where you're asking from, "text field" is an extremely vague term, and there is nothing in Delphi anywhere close to this name, unless you're referring to very specific database/driver/component combinations. Otherwise, if I'm not mistaken, you're referring to a `TEdit` control, otherwise generally known as a "text box" or "input" control, where a user inputs a `String` value. Even the word "field" is extremely vague, and could mean many, many different things. For example, "field" commonly identifies a member of an object in Delphi, which surely isn't what you mean.

Comment: PS - There's nothing "practical" or "real-life" about what you're trying to do.

Comment: It's practical for me, not meant to be distributed. Yes, I mean TEdit control. Why is everyone so hostile? I asked a harmless question looking for pointers. Isn't it a theoretically valid question? For example, there's a game called Dota2, and some apps exist that actually listen to the game IRL and present data accordingly. These apps are legal and helpful. How do you "listen" to a Delphi program from outside the program? What's wrong with asking this question? I put the Delphi tag because I know for sure the program is old Delphi. The solution, however, can be in any language.

Comment: I would better try to analyze what kind of database that is.

Comment: @JerryDodge: they are called text fields in e.g. macOS.

Comment: @Rudy No doubt, but this has nothing to do with any Apple products :-) Considering the age of said application, it was likely designed long before Firemonkey was even dreamed of. Anyway, "text field" is still very vague, no matter what platform or even programming language you're using.

Comment: @Jerry: but it explains the terminology. The word "text field" is not so uncommon for an edit box or whatever you call it.

Comment: @Rudy Indeed, that's why I suggested the correction to a `TEdit` control. But for all we know, based on how the question was worded, it could have also meant a field in a database table, or on an object, as mentioned. Kinda like the term "window" could mean different things. The thing you look outside through from the inside, a box which appears on your computer screen, or perhaps a philosophical perspective of "seeing things". But the fact remains that OP needs to be clear which definition they intend in their question, and not later on in the comments.

Comment: _"and later on develop something to automatically upload the info in bulk to our own DB"_, depends on used databases. Some DBMS allows linking of different DBMS types and there can be enough e.g. creating a trigger (with no client app. programming). Could you include also used database server types?

Answer (score 5):

I do this all the time to essentially automate a very old app on XP.
This is from 2000 and only used on XP.

- Use Spy or EnumWindows to get the data required for FindWindow to return the correct handle to your text boxes
- Then use SendMessage with AttachThreadInput and WM_GETTEXT
- Run that inside a Thread periodically probing the Text Fields

If it needs to be bullet proof then look into Hooks, madCodeHook is easy but you will need to prove you aren't doing anything a good hacker learns from his buddies in the first five minutes.

Some code to get you started:

```
function MySendMessageEx(const handle: THandle; const MessageID: Cardinal; const wParam, lParam: integer): integer;
var
  ThisThreadID      : DWord;
  AttachToThreadID  : DWord;
begin
  ThisThreadID := GetCurrentThreadID;
  AttachToThreadID := GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle, nil);
  Result := 0;
  if ThisThreadID <> AttachToThreadID then
  begin
    if AttachThreadInput(ThisThreadID, AttachToThreadID, True) then
    try
      Result := SendMessage(handle, MessageID, wParam, lParam);
    finally
      AttachThreadInput(ThisThreadID, AttachToThreadID, false);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

and:

```
  SetString(Result, Buffer, MySendMessageEx(AHandle, WM_GETTEXT, SizeOf(Buffer), Integer(@Buffer)));
```

Comment: Not bad, but I would rather use `WPARAM(Length(Buffer)), LPARAM(@Buffer)` instead of `SizeOf()`and the `Integer()` cast.

Comment: @Rudy, sure and if I ever needed it I would rewrite, but would use UIntPtr to replace LPARAM.

Comment: I would not use `UIntPtr`!. Always use the types/names that the (C) originals use, like `DWORD`, `WPARAM`, `LPARAM`, etc. That ensures that you won't have to change anything later on. if they change, such definitions will be changed in the runtime units too. Don't translate them further than that.